# Resizing object distorts it (Illustrator CC 2018)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resize, distort

[image]

after resizing

[image: resized object]

I've tried turning off snap to pixel as suggested by someone in a similar thread but it didn't work.
Does anyone know how I can resize this without messing up all the lines?

Comment: A sure fire way to get rid of the issue with little effort is to make it into a symbol and scale the symbol.

Answer (score 13):

Before resizing, deselect all and double click the Scale Tool → uncheck **Scale Strokes and Effects** and **Scale Corners**:

[image]

Select your artwork and scale it.

Additionally, you can set this to be default in Illustrator's general settings.

Edit → Preferences → General or using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I would have thought those options would need to be ON, not off?

Comment: On or off depending what you want to get.

Answer (score -3):

Expand appearance and voilà you're done.